# D3 el zoom solo afecta a los ejes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3-v4.js

Estoy usando la libreria `D3.js`, y estoy creando un grafico de tipo scatter dividido en cuatro cuadrantes. Por ahora he conseguido dividir el scatter en los cuadrantes y pintar cada cuadrante de un color e insertar los datos.

Me he puesto a aplicar la funcion de `zoom` y funciona mas o menos. Me aplica el zoom en los ejes (cambia la escala), pero los puntos de los datos se mantienen fijos y el color de los cuadrantes tambien.

Supongo que me faltan un para de lineas de codigo para definir los cambios en los puntos y los cuadrantes pero no se como introducirlas ya que soy muy nuevo en `D3.js`.

Aqui teneis el codigo:

```
            //Alto y ancho
            var w = 500;
            var h = 500;
            var padding = 0;

            var maxx = 0.30
            var minx = -0.30
            var maxy = 6
            var miny = -6
            //Static dataset
            var dataset = [
                            [0.12, 4], [0.05, 3], [0.15, -3], [-0.20, -5], [-0.10, 3]
                          ];

            //Dynamic, random dataset
            /*var dataset = [];                 //Initialize empty array
            var numDataPoints = 50;             //Number of dummy data points to create
            var xRange = Math.random() * 0.25;  //Max range of new x values
            var yRange = Math.random() * 5; //Max range of new y values
            for (var i = 0; i < numDataPoints; i++) {                   //Loop numDataPoints times
                var newNumber1 = Math.round(Math.random() * xRange);    //New random integer
                var newNumber2 = Math.round(Math.random() * yRange);    //New random integer
                dataset.push([newNumber1, newNumber2]);                 //Add new number to array
            }*/

            //Funciones de escala
            var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                                 .domain([minx, maxx])
                                 .range([padding, h]);

            var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                                 .domain([miny, maxy])
                                 .range([h, padding]);

            var rScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                                 .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d[1]; })])
                                 .range([2, 6]);

            //Eje x
            var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
                .scale(xScale);;

            //Eje y
            var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
                .scale(yScale);

            //Crear el elemento svg
            var svg = d3.select("#linegraph")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w)
                        .attr("height", h);



            /*
            //Create labels
            svg.selectAll("text")
               .data(dataset)
               .enter()
               .append("text")
               .text(function(d) {
                    return d[0] + "," + d[1];
               })
               .attr("x", function(d) {
                    return xScale(d[0]);
               })
               .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return yScale(d[1]);
               })
               .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
               .attr("font-size", "11px")
               .attr("fill", "red");
            */

            //Colores
            var c1 = svg.append("rect")
                .attr("width", (w/2) - padding)             
                .attr("height", (h/2)- padding)
                .attr("transform", "translate("+padding+","+padding+")")
                .attr("fill", "yellow");

            var c2 = svg.append("rect")
                .attr("width", (w/2) - padding)             
                .attr("height", (h/2)- padding)
                .attr("transform", "translate("+w/2+","+padding+")")
                .attr("fill", "green");

            var c3 = svg.append("rect")
                .attr("width", (w/2) - padding)             
                .attr("height", (h/2)- padding)
                .attr("transform", "translate("+padding+","+h/2+")")
                .attr("fill", "red");

            var c4 = svg.append("rect")
                .attr("width", (w/2) - padding)             
                .attr("height", (h/2)- padding)
                .attr("transform", "translate("+w/2+","+h/2+")")
                .attr("fill", "orange");

            //Añadimos el eje x
            var gX = svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h/2) + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

            //Añadimos el eje y
            var gY = svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w/2)  + ",0)")
                .call(yAxis);

            //Creamos los puntos
            var datos = svg.selectAll("circle")
               .data(dataset)
               .enter()
               .append("circle")
               .attr("cx", function(d) {
                    return xScale(d[0]);
               })
               .attr("cy", function(d) {
                    return yScale(d[1]);
               })
               .attr("r", function(d) {
                    return 5;
               });


//--------------------------------- ZOOM---------------------------------------------------------------------              
            var zoom = d3.zoom()
                .scaleExtent([1, 40])
                .translateExtent([[-100, -100], [w + 90, h + 100]])
                .on("zoom", zoomed);

            svg.call(zoom);
            function zoomed() {
                svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
                gX.call(xAxis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleX(xScale)));
                gY.call(yAxis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleY(yScale)));        
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que hacer un par de cosas para que te funcione. La primera al igual que añades una referencia a los ejes cuando haces zoom tienes que hacerla a los datos.

`datos.attr("transform",d3.event.transform);`

La segunda es aplicarselo a los cuadrantes. Aqui bien, no tienes que añadir una referencia a cada cuadrante.

```
c1.attr("transform",d3.event.transform);
c2.attr("transform",d3.event.transform);
c3.attr("transform",d3.event.transform);
c4.attr("transform",d3.event.transform);
```

Ya que todos se irian a la posicion del primero y se montarian uno encima de otro.

Tiene que meterlos en un grupo, y aplicar la transformacion a este mismo de esta manera:

```
grupo = svg.append("svg:g");

            var c2 = grupo.append("rect")
                .attr("width", (w/2) - padding)             
                .attr("height", (h/2)- padding)
                .attr("transform", "translate("+w/2+","+padding+")")
                .attr("fill", "green");

            var c1 = grupo.append("rect")
                .attr("width", (w/2) - padding)             
                .attr("height", (h/2)- padding)
                .attr("transform", "translate("+padding+","+padding+")")
                .attr("fill", "yellow");


            var c3 = grupo.append("rect")
                .attr("width", (w/2) - padding)             
                .attr("height", (h/2)- padding)
                .attr("transform", "translate("+padding+","+h/2+")")
                .attr("fill", "red");

            var c4 = grupo.append("rect")
                .attr("width", (w/2) - padding)             
                .attr("height", (h/2)- padding)
                .attr("transform", "translate("+w/2+","+h/2+")")
                .attr("fill", "orange");
```

Y la funcion de zoom debe quedar algo asi:

```
    function zoomed() {
        var posicionIni = w/2;              
        svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
        gX.call(xAxis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleX(xScale)));
        gY.call(yAxis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleY(yScale)));        
        datos.attr("transform",d3.event.transform);
        grupo.attr("transform",d3.event.transform);


    }
```